# The specified task executable cmd.exe could not be run. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I recently started getting this error intermittently when running or building a solution in Visual Studio 2010:

> The specified task executable cmd.exe could not be run. The process cannot access the file 'c:\temp\etc' because it is being used by another process.

There are [similar problems](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/caffd893-3d5c-495e-908f-e763e0824e4e/intermittent-build-busy-errors?forum=vcgeneral) reported elsewhere, due to things like two projects building to the same folder, or anti-virus issues, but none of them are the problem in this case. I've reduced the solution to a single project and it still happens.

Comment: Changing the TMP environment variable worked for me, see answers [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37053112/msbuild-error-the-specified-task-executable-cmd-exe-could-not-be-run-the-proce)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was a service my employer recently installed, called [AppSense Application Manager Agent](http://www.appsense.com/products/desktop/desktopnow/application-manager), which is designed to limit my access to admin-type features on the PC.

Luckily I still have access to the services control panel, and disabling the service fixed the problem.

Comment: I had the same problem in Visual Studio 2010 after restaring my VDI. I couldn't build a project of ASP.NET MVC 3 application type. The error pointed to NuGet.targets file, but in details it was written that there is some locked file in 'C:\temp\...'. So I found your post and AppSense Application Manager Agent in services. I stopped it, disabled and it worked! You saved my time. Thank you!

Comment: I had to do the same- VS2015

Comment: .... I've been trying to find the answer to this issue for days.  THANK YOU