# MSbuild error: The specified task executable cmd.exe could not be run. The process cannot access the file, because it is being used by another process

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild

Right after a particular windows update, MSBUild has been throwing this:

```
The specified task executable cmd.exe could not be run. The process cannot access the file, because it is being used by another process
```

This issue is very persistent. I tried increasing the "maximum number of parallel project builds" but to no avail. I didn't find any other software that was restricting non-admin access to the location that is mentioned by MSBuild.

Anyone else in a similar situation?

Comment: Execute build from command line using `msbuild <myproject> /v:d` and paste larger snippet that contains error message and relevant context messages.

Comment: Here it is:`(PostBuildEvent target) ->
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(4264,5): error MSB6003: The specified task executable "cmd.exe" could not be run. The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\ctuft\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp
8c89d6440ec743acba7e22d98d773e3b.exec.cmd' because it is being used by another process. [D:\mysolution\WebAPI\mysolution.csproj]`

Comment: I am trying to build a solution here, not a project.

Comment: Are you running any anti-virus? Try disabling all monitoring and anti-viral software.

Comment: We are using Mcafee, and I did disable whatever I can from the MAcfee console, but I still get the same error. :(

Comment: Another thing I would like to add is that , at the same time even the Pscx module, "Expand-Archive" is throwing errors. I have a hunch that the update might be the cause of this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved right after another Windows update.

Answer (score 1):

We encountered this same issue building our C# solution from a recently updated Visual Studio 2017, on Windows 10, with McAfee virus scan active (and locked down by our IT folks).

In our case, changing the TEMP and (especially) TMP environment variables to be c:\temp instead of c:\users{username}\AppData\Local\Temp and then re-starting Visual Studio got us past this very frustrating issue.

(Our first fix attempt set TMP to c:\windows\temp but that did not resolve the issue).

Answer (score 0):

Once I turned on Diagnostic logging for MSBUILD (Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run), I noticed that my problem was with NuGet restore:

```
2>C:\Code\EEE\Dev\Current\Source\.nuget\NuGet.targets(92,9): error
  MSB6003: The specified task executable "cmd.exe" could not be run. The
  process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\
  tmp271c9a670c43427c9ba44267a4152430.exec.cmd' because it is being used by 
  another process.
2>Done executing task "Exec" -- FAILED. (TaskId:13)
2>Done building target "RestorePackages" in project
 "TTT.EEE.Tests.Unit.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:11)
```